# how to manage returned customer in oauth 2.0 php?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, access-token, bearer-token, refresh-token

I am new to oauth 2.0 and able to implement it and able to login. but i am not able to handle the returned customer as it always throws to login page of mine after expiration of access token which is 1 hrs. whereas, it should generate new access token with the help of refresh token. I have referred this document to implement this.

https://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/cookbook/

when I click login button, i am redirecting it to the auth page. where it is checking if user_id(which i am getting after login) is present, if not, then redirect to login page. I am getting these parameter on auth page

1: Redirect_uri
     2: Scope
     3: client_id
     4: state

and I am getting these parameter on token page

1: Grant_type
     2: code
     3: client_id
     4: redirect_uri

all the value is getting stored in DB after generating. Access token is expiring in an hour and after that when i try to access the api, it ask for the login again.

```
if(!isset($_GET['user_id']) && empty($_GET['user_id'])){
    exit(getToLogin($client_id,$state,$response_type,$redirect_uri));
}else{
    $userid = $_GET['user_id'];
    $is_authorized = true;
    $server->handleAuthorizeRequest($request, $response, $is_authorized, $userid);
    if ($is_authorized) {
            $code = substr($response->getHttpHeader('Location'), strpos($response->getHttpHeader('Location'), 'code=')+5, 40);
    }
}
```

If need any else info, please let me know.

Comment: please let me know anything. I really need help on this ASAP.

Comment: so no oauth expert here?